# Register-WmiEvent (Win32_ProcessStopTrace) - How to use variables in -Action switch?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have the following function where I register for the stop service event. 
Once the service is stopped, I want to display that ServiceName in the event. But, somehow, the code below does not wants to print service name ?

*See the `Write-Host $ControllerSvc,” stopped ”` in the -Action switch* It prints justs " stopped". But, if I change the code to **this it is fine** -

*`Write-Host $e.ProcessName,” stopped ”`*  (which I do not want because my process or imagename is same for all the services. Its something like svchost)

```
function Stop-MyService($SystemName)
{
    $ControllerSvc = $SystemName+"Controller"

    $svc = gwmi win32_service -filter "name = `"$ControllerSvc`""   
    $ControllerPid = $svc.ProcessId


    Register-WMIEvent -query “SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace WHERE ProcessID=$ControllerPid” -SourceIdentifier “ControllerSvcEvent” -action { 
    $e = $Event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent
    Write-Host $ControllerSvc,” stopped ” #**** never prints out the variable****
    unregister-event -sourceIdentifier “ControllerSvcEvent”    
    }

    Stop-Service $ControllerSvc
}
```

> **NB**:For sake of simplicity I am showing one service here. Actually
>   there are multiple services where stopping one of them stops the
>   others. So, I want to display the service names which are getting
>   stopped in the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing `$ControllerSvc` through `-MessageData` parameter of `Register-WMIEvent`, then it should be accessible through `$Event`, according to [this article](http://www.colorconsole.de/PS_Windows/en/Register-WmiEvent.htm).

Comment: Does not work. I tried this -     `Register-WMIEvent -query “SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace WHERE ProcessID=$ControllerPid” -SourceIdentifier “ControllerSvcEvent” -MessageData $ControllerSvc -action { 
    $e = $Event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent
    Write-Host $ControllerSvc,” stopped ” 
    unregister-event -sourceIdentifier “ControllerSvcEvent”    
    }
`

Comment: Yeah, but you need to change `Write-Host $ControllerSvc` to `Write-Host $Event.MessageData`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take on the task with an alternate query, registering for Win32_Service modification events where Win32_Service.State value is 'Stopped'. I used $Event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance.Name to get the service name:

```
function Stop-MyService($SystemName)
{
    $ControllerSvc = $SystemName

    $query = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 2 " +
             "WHERE TargetInstance Isa 'Win32_Service' " +
             "AND TargetINstance.Name = '" + $ControllerSvc + "' " +
             "AND TargetInstance.State = 'Stopped'"

    $action = 
    { 
        Write-Host $Event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance.Name," stopped "
        Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier "ControllerSvcEvent"    
    }

    Register-WMIEvent -query $query -SourceIdentifier "ControllerSvcEvent" -action $action
}

Stop-MyService 'MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS'
```

I used SQL Server Express for testing.

Comment: Thanks. I have upvoted. Nice alternative. But, since my question was very specific to variable passing, I chose the other answer as the accepted one.